# Can we expect to see already existing stablecoins on Cardano?

Tags: stablecoins

I know there is a new stablecoin (AgeUSD) that is supposed to be released on the Cardano blockchain, but I haven't heard anything about having other stablecoins, like Tether (USDT), be added to the Cardano blockchain. Is this something we can hope to see, or is the creation of AgeUSD going to make the addition of Tether not necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the [Liquity team](https://www.liquity.org/) is interested to have their protocol deployed on Cardano too. But it is too early to tell.